# How to write .netrc for two accounts for skipping typing password when to git push?

Tags: git, passwords

It is simple to skip typing password when to execute `git psuh` command.

```
vim  .netrc
machine github.com
login user1
password  pass-user1
```

How to write .netrc for two accounts  for skipping typing password when to git push?

It is no use to write the .netrc as following.

```
vim  .netrc
machine github.com
login user1
password  pass-user1
login user2
password  pass-user2
```

Edit .netrc as below according to VonC.

```
machine github.com login user1 password  pass-user1
machine github.com login user2 password  pass-user2
```

Strange errors for git push.

```
git push -u origin master -f
remote: Permission to user2/test.git denied to user1.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user2/test/': The requested URL returned error: 403

git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/user2/test (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user2/test (push)
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax would repeat the machine.
And you can write both entries on their separate lines:

```
machine github.com login user1 password  pass-user1
machine github.com login user2 password  pass-user2
```

But then, make sure your origin remote URL specifies one of the two users:

If you already *had* an `origin` remote defined, change it with:

```
git remote set-up origin https://user2@github.com/user2/arepo.git
```

But if you are using a new local repo, without any `origin`, add it with:

```
git remote add origin https://user2@github.com/user2/arepo.git
```

Answer (score 2):

1.setting in .netrc for two accounts.

```
machine github.com login user1 password  pass-user1
machine github.com login user2 password  pass-user2
```

2.add origin for git push.

```
git remote add origin   https://user2@github.com/user2/arepo.git
```

Not

```
git remote set-up origin https://user2@github.com/user2/arepo.git
```